Truly selfless acts
Is there an example for a truly selfless (/random) act, with no benefit to the actor?
consider that benefit for the actor could also be in the form of

good conscience
admiration / prominence (can also be achieved for something negative)
benefiting from it further down the line (investment)
the hope of being in good favor towards a chosen deity
the sense of intelectual superiority by proving this post wrong

I believe, that the answer to it is "no", but I like to be proven wrong.

We are not even strictly rational in our intentions... the burden is on you to sustain the quite unsustainable idea that we are pure utilitarianists and there is nothing else to it.

I upvoted your question.

Related post

Thank you for your comments. I'm a regular stackoverflow user, but new to the philosophy stackexchange (and also a non-native speaker). Can you perhaps help me improve my question by editng it if needed?

Maybe, there is an example of a truly selfless act: saving a sleeping man from a falling tree without wanting to, with no witnesses, and feeling no empathy or sense of duty.
Does just because it was an automatic reaction to a dangerous situation.

@YannMarchal I feel like I should have explicitly stated that I only meant intentional actions. My bad. Also, offtopic: how do you save someone from a falling tree without wanting to? Do you accidentally drag his sleeping form out of the danger zone, or do you absorb the impact by having the three fall on your own head?
